# jquery opening tags omitted - clarification on how it works

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery expression which appends tags to a table. It only specifies closing tags but it seems to work.

```
parent.$("#uploaded-files").append(
    $("<tr/>")
    .append($("<td/>").text(file.fileId))
    .append($("<td/>").text(file.fileName))
    .append($("<td/>").text(file.fileSize))
    .append($("<td/>").text(file.fileType))
    .append($("<td/>")
    .html("<a href='controller/get/"+index+".htm'>Click</a>"))
)
```

I didn't know you could do this in jQuery. It looks like it allows you to place the closing tags in there where the opening tags would go. Can someone help me with an explanation on this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Comment: `<tr/>` is not a closing tag.. a closing tag is `</tr>`

Comment: Rory posted the link of the documentation as it explains in there. API documentation should always be where you first look to understand a library API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't closing tags (end tags), they're *self-closing* tags. The end tag for a `td` would be `</td>`, not `<td/>`. `<td/>` is a shorthand (and technically incorrect*, for HTML) way of writing `<td></td>`. It works with jQuery, but [you can also just leave the `/` out of those instead](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2). jQuery treats `"<td>"`, `"<td/>"`, and `"<td></td>"` exactly the same way (on purpose).

---

* Why using a self-closing tag for `td` is incorrect in HTML: Because [tags for elements that aren't void cannot be self-closing in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags), only XHTML. So in HTML, `<br>` and `<br/>` are both valid, because `br` is a void element; but `<div>` and `<div/>` are both *start* tags for a `div`; `<div/>` != `<div></div>` in HTML (it does in XHTML).

Answer (score 1):

`$("<td/>")` is same as `$("<td></td>")` in jquery.

You can do either way in case like:

```
$('.selector').append('<td class="someClass" />');
```

Or,

```
$('.selector').append('<td class="someClass"></td>');
```

Thus, this is a short-hand for opening and closing the tag.